# Ubuntu sounds issues that get fixed by playing a YT video?

Tags: ubuntu, audio, output

I've been having sound connectivity issue for a while and tried getting to the RCA on a few occasions.

I have Ubuntu 22.04 with a Yeti Microphone and CR-X Speakers and two aux ports on my tower (one in front and one in the back)

After a restart my microphone and speakers change within the Sound settings - I tried declaring the device as static within the config file and pulling the name from the command

```
pactl list short sinks # audio
```

When the issue is resolved:

1. Going to sound settings and cycling through each option on Input, then selecting the correct Microphone option, then cycling through each Output device before finally selecting "Line Out - Bult-In AUdio"
2. Opening Firefox and playing a YouTube video sometimes fixes the issue - if another audio player is used the issue continues. (Including built-in one)
3. Sometimes switching the aux port fixes the issue.

Sometimes only one or a combination of those steps resolves the issue.

This has been bothering me for months and I've tried resolving this and finding the RCA for months. Any documentation or link would be helpful.

Edit: Sorry, I'm not sure about the Stack Exchange edit post etiquette. Thank you, Peregrino69 - I did forget to ask the actual question.

I'm not really getting any error logs - well I'm unsure where sound device error logs would output to. I tried the following command, without luck.

```
cat /var/log/syslog | grep sinks
```

I am trying to get to the RCA (Root Cause Analysis) - as in why is this happening? Also, I would like to implement less "barbaric" steps of resolution - clicking on each Input and Output device. I would love to run a bash script on startup if I knew what to hunt down. The second question is: How would I fix the issue to not reoccur on startup?

Comment: Welcome to U&L. Good writeup on the steps you've taken to resolve the issue. However you seem to have forgotten one minor detail, explaining what exactly is the issue you need to resolve :-) Please [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/739217/edit) your question to add the missing info. Also please add any relevant configurations, possible error messages etc. Don't put text output as images, rather copy-paste it as text. In general editing the question to add info is better than using comments, so everything  relevant stays readily available.